# how to pivot dataframe without adding column and index name

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

pivot is a great function but results in a dataframe with a few extra info that I don't need: How can I achieve below? I do not need "bar" or "foo", and I want to make the df more concise. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `index` and `columns` names to `None`:

```
df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None
```

Or use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None).df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```